# How much taxes to pay after selling stocks?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

Can anyone tell me how much taxes I will be liable to pay to IRS after selling some US stocks?
I have around $20K and I need the money, I invested for almost 2 years and it gave me around 400% profit.
I invested $3,700 and it says I profited $15,306.46, making it close to $20K. Will I be taxed on $15K or $20K, and what percentage ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should only be taxed on the capital gain, $15,306.

Comment: Will the % be the same as my tax bracket ? So, I'm married , no kids and 2018 tax bracket for married filling jointly , would put me in the 22%. Does that mean I will have to pay 22% of that $15K ?

Comment: I don't know, which is why I commented rather than answered. USA capital gains taxes are weird.

Comment: Don't forget that unless you wait until 1/1/18 to sell it, you're going to be paying 2017 rates, not 2018, and either way you'll probably have a significant amount withheld to pay the tax.

Answer (score 2):

Long-term capital gains (held more than 1 year) are taxed at special rates, while short-term capital gains are taxed at the same rate as your ordinary income.

For 2017:

```
Tax bracket    Long-term capital gains rate
10%            0%
15%            0%
25%            15%
28%            15%
33%            15%
35%            15%
39.6%          20%
```

Per the name, you're only taxed on the gain, so your proceeds from sale less cost to acquire. Remember that your capital gain is included in figuring out which bracket you're in, but only the capital gain is taxed at the higher rate if it bumps you to a higher bracket, and even then it's marginal, so only the piece above the threshold is taxed at the higher rate.

For example, if you were $5,000 from the top end of the 35% tax bracket and realized $15,000 in long-term capital gain, you'd pay 15% capital gains tax on $5,000, and 20% on the rest.